# Running lynx via sudo

Tags: lynx

I am trying to run `Lynx` under `apache user via sudo`, but it seems that lynx tries to access my home directory:

```
    $ sudo -u apache lynx
    /home/ssmirnov/: No such directory
```

I have such permissions on my home directory: `drwx------`

Can you advice me how to run Lynx under another user?

Comment: Show the output of running `grep apache /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

You might try using sudo's `-H` option.  It sets `$HOME` to the home directory of the user you're trying to run as.  Perhaps lynx is looking for a file there, i dunno.  (It doesn't seem to have a problem on my machine...but eh.)

`-i` might work as well; it basically sets the environment up as if the user had logged in, including cd'ing to their home directory.  Note, that means starting the shell specified for that user, running login scripts, and all that.  If the user's not allowed to log in, this will likely fail.

If you *want* to run it from your home directory, for example to download something to that location, of course you'll have to grant access to `apache` somehow.  This can be done on ext* filesystems on most modern Linux systems (without granting everyone access) by saying something like `setfacl -m u:apache:rwx $HOME`.  In a pinch, you could temporarily put `apache` in your group and grant group `rwx` permissions on your homedir...but unless this is your home machine, i wouldn't do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither -H not -i didn't resolve this issue :( I didn't change home directory permissions because I need to run lynx via script on different environments.

Comment: Any particular reason you need lynx for a script?   It's made more for interactive use; in scripts, most people use `wget`.